Ruby application MySql connection issue
I have this application running on Heroku,
I am trying to change DB from ClearDb to JawsDB  (both MySql hosting sites) on application running Rails 6.1.7
For some reason the connection isn't successful, I am getting the below error
Update adding bunch of info based on comments
I want to make a clarification that the app was working fine with clear db before the shift..and i am able to connect to the new MySql DB using jaws with a windows external client (HeidiSql)
I have these entry in the Gemfile
gem "mini_portile2", "2.8.1"  
gem "mysql2", "0.5.5"  
gem "cocoon"    

This is my database.yml
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>

This is the config in Heroku
DATABASE_URL=mysql://USER:PASS@HOST.amazonaws.com:3306/DB
JAWSDB_URL=mysql://USER:PASS@HOST.amazonaws.com:3306/DB
DB_ADAPTER=mysql2
DB_HOST=HOST.amazonaws.com
DB_PASSWORD=**************
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=USER

Bundle install result
Fetching https://github.com/tmesquita/rails_admin_bulk_paranoia_delete.git
Bundle complete! 83 Gemfile dependencies, 176 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`

my DB Version:
MySql version 8.0.35  
bundle show mysql2 -> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5  
I have DB_ADAPTER as mysql - also tried mysql2 

When I execute this command ** bundle exec rails c **
Its giving this message:
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require': Could not load the 'mysql' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile. (LoadError)

This is the app start error:
653342+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.1.7 application starting in production 
653351+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
815587+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
815645+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require': Could not load the 'mysql' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
815646+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.7/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
815647+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
815647+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
815647+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
815648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1205:in `resolve_pool_config'
815648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1046:in `establish_connection'
815648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:52:in `establish_connection'
815648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.4.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:252:in `establish_connection'
815649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:222:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
815649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
815649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
815649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
815650+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
815651+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
815651+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
815651+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
815651+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:217:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
815652+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
815652+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
815653+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
815660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
815660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
815660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
815660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
815662+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
815663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
815666+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
815666+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
815667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
815668+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
815677+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
815677+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
815678+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
815678+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
815679+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
815679+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
815679+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
815680+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
815681+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
815682+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
815685+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
815686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
815687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
815687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
815688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
815696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
815696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
815697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
815697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
815697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
815697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
815698+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
815699+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
815707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
815707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
815707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
815707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'


Add your database.yml and your gem file

The correct adapter name is mysql2. "I have DB_ADAPTER as mysql - also tried mysql2" if this is an ENV variable it's not something that Rails supports out of the box AFAIK. The only ENV variable that changes the database adapter is DATABASE_URL which Heroku automatically uses if you have the Postgres addon attached to your app. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

mysql is the original Ruby adapter gem which saw it's latest release in 2013. mysql2 was originally created by Github in 2011 and is actively maintained.

1. Configure Gemfile
By default RoR comes with sqlite3. Edit the Gemfile and comment/remove the sqlite3 entry and place the below entry:
gem 'mysql2'
Next, run the below command:
$bundle install
2. Configure database.yml file with database connection settings
Edit the config/database.yml file as per your environment settings. Below we have used the 3 environments — Development, Test and Production
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: developmentdb
 username: 
 password: 
 host: localhost
 encoding: utf8

test:
 database: testdb
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 username: 
 password: 
 host: localhost

production:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: Railsdb
 username: 
 password: 
 host: localhost
 encoding: utf8


Heroku If you’re using Ruby on Rails and the mysql2 gem, you will need to change the mysql:// scheme in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL to mysql2://

heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'


The question includes "bundle show mysql2 -> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5" which means that gem is already in the Gemfile.

I see, I found this:
If you’re using Ruby on Rails and the mysql2 gem, you will need to change the mysql:// scheme in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL to mysql2://
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'

Yeah the question is missing a bunch of information but I would assume that the DATABASE_URL env var is overriding the settings or that they are using the wrong name mysql instead of mysql2.

Thank you for your help. I updated the question with more details as you pointed out

Have you run the command to configure DATABASE_URL? If so, did it work as expected?
